# Cant add Object to Object Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to add to the var objectsArray some new content. How can I do this? The append method doesn't work for me.

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String ]!
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()   

objectsArray = [Objects(sectionName: "FirstSection", sectionObjects: ["hi"]),
                Objects(sectionName: "SecondSection", sectionObjects: ["Thomas Schmidt"])]
```

Comment: Can you the code that shows your attempt at using `append`? What error did it produce?

Comment: objectsArray.append(Objects(sectionName: "test", sectionObjects: ["checked"]))

Comment: You still haven't explained why `append` didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

try this, There is not any Problem with your Question.

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String ]!
}

var objectsArrayUsingAppendFunc = [Objects]()
var objectsArrayWithoutAppendFunc = [Objects]()

objectsArrayUsingAppendFunc.append(Objects(sectionName: "FirstSection", sectionObjects: ["hi"]))
objectsArrayUsingAppendFunc.append(Objects(sectionName: "SecondSection", sectionObjects: ["Thomas Schmidt"]))
objectsArrayUsingAppendFunc.append(Objects(sectionName: "THIRD SECTI0N", sectionObjects: ["THIRD NAME"]))

objectsArrayWithoutAppendFunc = [ Objects(sectionName: "FirstSection", sectionObjects: ["hi"]),
                                  Objects(sectionName: "SecondSection", sectionObjects: ["Thomas Schmidt"]),
                                  Objects(sectionName: "THIRD SECTI0N", sectionObjects: ["THIRD NAME"])
                                ]

print(objectsArrayWithoutAppendFunc)
print("-----")
print(objectsArrayUsingAppendFunc)
```

Comment: Add some context to your answer by explaining what you have done and how it solves the issue. Just dumping some code is not very helpful for OP or future readers of this question and a well described answer is more likely to get up voted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, to append an object. It is working fine.
From your above code, I just added one Append line.

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}
var objectsArray = [Objects]()
        objectsArray = [Objects(sectionName: "FirstSection", sectionObjects: ["hi"]),Objects(sectionName: "SecondSection", sectionObjects: ["Thomas Schmidt"])]

objectsArray.append(Objects(sectionName: "ThirdSection", sectionObjects: ["hello"]))
print(objectsArray)
```

Comment: Add some context to your answer by explaining what you have done and how it solves the issue. Just dumping some code is not very helpful for OP or future readers of this question and a well described answer is more likely to get up voted.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Okay sure

Comment: @Max I hope this answer works for you. Let me know in case of any further help needed.